# Angular 2 copy to clipboard button

Tags: angular

How do I make a button copy an input value to the clipboard?

I've seen this: [How do I copy to clipboard in Angular 2 Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328159/how-do-i-copy-to-clipboard-in-angular-2-typescript)

but it's not longer compactible from the latest angular changes with ngModule (RC5+)

Comment: What is the issue? What have you tried? https://plnkr.co/edit/ryF9DqDaIPIbQvKLp3OU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use many different libraries to accomplish this task in a few different ways. Problem is, they are not well documented and are kind of use-case specific. Take some time to learn about Document from angular/core. Here's the solution I ended up with:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onCopy() {
    var el = this.document.getElementById('targetDiv')
    el.setAttribute('contenteditable','true')
    el.focus()
    this.document.execCommand('selectAll')
    this.document.execCommand('copy');
    el.setAttribute('contenteditable','false')
    el.blur()
  }


}
```

And in template

```
<div id="targetDiv" contenteditable="false">
 <p><strong>Test: </strong> 1 2 3 4 </p>
 <h2> mic check    </h2>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="onCopy()" >
 Copy
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is **RC7 version** of the same.

**Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/hSP42BLoxX2uodZZ2uMj?p=preview**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ClipboardDirective} from './clipboard.directive';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,ClipboardDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Plnkr link is leading to a new project not a demo.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple pure Angular2 and javascript solution that doesn't require any libraries and which can be used in an angular component. You could turn it into a service or make it more generic if needed but this will establish the basic idea.

Currently browsers only allow text to be copied to the clipboard from the Selection in an or . This can implemented in div

```
(.html file)
<div id="inputId">Some texts</div>
<button (click)="copyToClipboard()'>click me</button>

//(.ts file)

public copyToClipboard(){
  var el = document.getElementById('inputId');
  el.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
  el.focus();
  document.execCommand('selectAll');
  document.execCommand('copy');
  el.setAttribute('contenteditable','false');
  el.blur();
}
```