# ngx-clipboard is not copying to clipboard when instead a callback method

Tags: angular, ngx-clipboard

I have a service that I am running to retrieve device information, and I want to copy that back to the clipboard once it has been retrieved. I have the following code:

```
callServiceToCopy() {
let stringData = '';
let thingName: string = this.route.snapshot.params['thingName'];
let curDevice = this.devicesService
                    .get(thingName)
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                      this.device = data;
                      stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
                      console.log(stringData);
                      this.copy(stringData);
                      console.log("Copy Complete");
  });
}

onCopyFailure() {
    alert('Failed to copy to clipboard user ');
}

copy(text) {
  console.log(text + ' sent to copy');
  this._clipboardService.copyFromContent(text);
}
```

If I have the __clipboardService outside of the callback, it is able to copy text to the clipboard. However, If I have it in the callback, it does not (and thus, does not have the device data). I did follow the Plunker information to get this up and running, and looked at the following question for guidance, but it falls a little show of my needs.

[StackOverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062477/angular2-ngx-clipboard-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) question as I think it may help. In essence, I think you need to bind `this` to your callback method, and pass that to the `subscribe`.