# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' in Angular

Tags: angular

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712642/cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefined-ngafterviewinit)

It did not help me.

**Code:**

```
@ViewChild('filter') filteru: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);
    Observable.fromEvent(this.filteru.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .debounceTime(150)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
        this.dataSource.filter = this.filteru.nativeElement.value;
      });
  }
```

I import this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```

Comment: any error popping up ?

Comment: are you sure that `this` is what you expect? (that it isn't undefinded) If it is undefinded, try adding `.bind(this)` after your subscription

Comment: If your could replicate the issue in a plunkr, that would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have missed the imports

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Working [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngclass?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)