# Angular 5 - Copy to clipboard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to implement an icon that when clicked will save a variable to the user's clipboard. I have currently tried several libraries and none of them have been able to do so.

How do I properly copy a variable to the user's clipboard in Angular 5?

Comment: you can use [ngxyz-c2c](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngxyz-c2c), there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: If you're using Angular Material then version 9.0.0 (released Feb 6th, 2020) introduced the super easy to use [clipboard package](https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview). See the Angular documentation and @Nabel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621480/245602).

Answer (score 372, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Copy any text

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="copyMessage('This goes to Clipboard')" value="click to copy" >Copy this</button>
```

**.ts file**

```
copyMessage(val: string){
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  }
```

---

**Solution 2:** Copy from a TextBox

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" value="User input Text to copy" #userinput>
      <button (click)="copyInputMessage(userinput)" value="click to copy" >Copy from Textbox</button>
```

**.ts file**

```
    /* To copy Text from Textbox */
  copyInputMessage(inputElement){
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-copy-to-clipboard)

---

**Solution 3:** Import a 3rd party directive [ngx-clipboard](https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-clipboard)

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ngxClipboard [cbContent]="Text to be copied">copy</button>
```

---

**Solution 4:** Custom Directive

If you prefer using a custom directive, Check Dan Dohotaru's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949299/443244) which is an elegant solution implemented using `ClipboardEvent`.

---

**Solution 5:** Angular Material

Angular material 9 + users can utilize the [built-in clipboard](https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview) feature to copy text. There are a few more customization available such as limiting the number of attempts to copy data.

Comment: Great idea, but I copyied your 2nd solution and I keep getting `Cannot read property 'select' of undefined` in angular 6. Is this angular6-compatible?

Comment: @slevin I don't think it is related to angular version in any way. DId you add ` #userinput` to your input?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile I checked again and again, but still the same error. This is my code `<input *ngIf="invitation_code" type="text" readonly   value="{{invitation_code}}" #userinput >
  <button *ngIf="code_success" (click)="copyInputMessage(userinput)" value="click to copy" > Copy code </button>` Thanks

Comment: You can even remove the `position`, `left`, `top`, and `opacity`. and replace it with a `selBox.style.height = '0';`

Comment: minor issue, should use const not let

Comment: how to check if copied from ts ?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile This method does not work for `focus trapped` elements. What is the solution for `focus trapped` elements? https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-clipboard/issues/152

Comment: I tried the solution 1, but document.executeCommand('copy') always returning false. any suggestion?

Comment: worth showing that solution 1 html could be changed to:

`<button (click)="copyMessage(copyButton.value)" value="click to copy" #copyButton>Copy this</button>`

Comment: the cool part about solution 1 is that you can encapsulate it in an injectable service

Comment: `ngx-clipboard` has a separate method `ClipboardService.copy()`.
So we can copy any text just in a template controller, without any things in html template. That's what I was looking for. Thank you! 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard

Comment: You should NEVER access the DOM directly in angular.  Make sure to [inject document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-service) the right way!

Comment: @Jonathan, works pretty well with injected `document` and a `ViewChild`, instead of inserting an element at runtime! :)

Answer (score 100):

I know this has already been highly voted in here by now, but I'd rather go for a custom directive approach and rely on the ClipboardEvent as @jockeisorby suggested, while also making sure the listener is correctly removed (same function needs to be provided for both the add and remove event listeners)

stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-labs-copy-clipboard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello%2Fhello.component.html)

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: '[copy-clipboard]' })
export class CopyClipboardDirective {

  @Input("copy-clipboard")
  public payload: string;

  @Output("copied")
  public copied: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {

    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.payload)
      return;

    let listener = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      let clipboard = e.clipboardData || window["clipboardData"];
      clipboard.setData("text", this.payload.toString());
      e.preventDefault();

      this.copied.emit(this.payload);
    };

    document.addEventListener("copy", listener, false)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener, false);
  }
}
```

and then use it as such

```
<a role="button" [copy-clipboard]="'some stuff'" (copied)="notify($event)">
  <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
  Copy
</a>

public notify(payload: string) {
   // Might want to notify the user that something has been pushed to the clipboard
   console.info(`'${payload}' has been copied to clipboard`);
}
```

Note: notice the `window["clipboardData"]` is needed for IE as it does not understand `e.clipboardData`

Comment: Kudos for making this a reusable directive. Great idea!

Comment: indeed, starting with version 12.x something, Safari is again problematic :)

Comment: a minimal workaround would be to create a range and add that range to the selection, a working solution would look like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-labs-copy-clipboard-r1

Comment: window["clipboardData"] is undefined for me in IE ? Any idea ?

Comment: it doesn't work on mobile, I used the ngx-clipboard plugin instead

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated

Answer (score 77):

I think this is a much more cleaner solution when copying text:

```
copyToClipboard(item) {
    document.addEventListener('copy', (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', (item));
      e.preventDefault();
      document.removeEventListener('copy', null);
    });
    document.execCommand('copy');
  }
```

And then just call `copyToClipboard` on click event in html. `(click)="copyToClipboard('texttocopy')"`.

Comment: does not work on IE due to the fact that e.clipboardData is not defined.

Comment: moreover the removelistener does not work either as the original listener needs to be passed as an argument

Comment: Look here for how to get the remove event listener working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843984/3849445

Comment: Works fine in Angular 6! Tested in Chrome. Thank you.

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated

Answer (score 42):

As of Angular Material v9, it now has a clipboard CDK

[Clipboard | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview)

It can be used as simply as

```
<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="This goes to Clipboard">Copy this</button>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Never knew a proper solution was there!

Comment: available from Angular Material v9.

Comment: But will it require all of the Angular Material to be installed to just achieve this simple copy to clipboard?

Comment: @muasif80 it is part of the cdk so you would only need to install that I believe

Comment: Yes, just install `ng add @angular/cdk` and in your `app.module.ts` add `import { ClipboardModule } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard'` and add it to your module imports: `imports: [ ..., ClipboardModule ]`.

Answer (score 29):

Copy using angular cdk,

Module.ts

```
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
```

Programmatically copy a string: MyComponent.ts,

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) {}

  copyHeroName() {
    this.clipboard.copy('Alphonso');
  }
}
```

Click an element to copy via HTML:

```
<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="longText" [cdkCopyToClipboardAttempts]="2">Copy text</button>
```

Reference:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview

Comment: This forces you to use Angular Material

Comment: This worked so much better than the other ones. I had bugs in the other copy examples and I already had cdk imported. yay!

Comment: @edu you don't necessarily need to install the whole ```@angular/material``` package, but just its peer dependency: ```@angular/cdk```

Answer (score 20):

Modified version of jockeisorby's answer that fixes the event handler not being properly removed.

```
copyToClipboard(item): void {
    let listener = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', (item));
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    document.addEventListener('copy', listener);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.removeEventListener('copy', listener);
}
```

Comment: Not working in Firefox. Error - `document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler`

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve this using Angular modules:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText('your text').then().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: I suggest to `await` the call, so nothing steals the focus before the operation is done.

Answer (score 9):

**It's simple bro**

in .html file

```
<button (click)="copyMessage('This goes to Clipboard')" value="click to copy" >Copy this</button>
```

in .ts file

```
copyMessage(text: string) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then().catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me `document.execCommand('copy')` was giving ***deprecated*** warning and the data I need to copy was inside `<div>` as **textNode** rather than `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

This is how I did it in Angular 7 (inspired by answers of @Anantharaman and @Codemaker):

```html
<div id="myDiv"> &lt &nbsp This is the text to copy. &nbsp &gt </div>
<button (click)="copyToClipboard()" class="copy-btn"></button>
```

```js
 copyToClipboard() {
    const content = (document.getElementById('myDiv') as HTMLElement).innerText;
    navigator['clipboard'].writeText(content).then().catch(e => console.error(e));

  }
}
```

Definitely not the best way, but it serves the purpose.

Comment: Thank you.  The other navigator.clipboard would throw an error, navigator['clipboard'] worked just fine.  Best way to do it without having to upgrade the entire code base to latest Angular.

Answer (score 2):

```
// for copy the text
import { Clipboard } from "@angular/cdk/clipboard"; // first import this in .ts
 constructor(
    public clipboard: Clipboard
  ) { }   
 <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"(click) = "onCopy('some text')" > Copy< /button>

 onCopy(value) {
     this.clipboard.copy(value);
    }


 // for paste the copied text on button click :here is code
    
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"(click) = "onpaste()" > Paste < /button>
    
    onpaste() {
      navigator['clipboard'].readText().then(clipText => {
        console.log(clipText);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand all the complicated code and using libraries to do something so simple. just do this:

html:

```
<span (mousedown)="copyText()">{{text}}</span>
```

ts:

```
copyText() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.text);
}
```

that's it!

Comment: by far, the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Below method can be used for copying the message:-

```
export function copyTextAreaToClipBoard(message: string) {
  const cleanText = message.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
  const x = document.createElement('TEXTAREA') as HTMLTextAreaElement;
  x.value = cleanText;
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(x);
}
```

Comment: This indeed is a good solution. I tried it for my application and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Angular and keep the code simple is to use this project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard

```
    <fa-icon icon="copy" ngbTooltip="Copy to Clipboard" aria-hidden="true" 
    ngxClipboard [cbContent]="target value here" 
    (cbOnSuccess)="copied($event)"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

Much More Easier [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJN4K.png)

```
let textToCopy: string = `\nAccess Token: ${conn.accessToken} \nInstance Url: ${conn.instanceUrl} \nOrg ID: ${conn.userInfo.organizationId}`;
navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggested solution works, we just need to change

```
selBox.value = val;
```

To

```
selBox.innerText = val;
```

i.e.,

HTML:

```
<button (click)="copyMessage('This goes to Clipboard')" value="click to copy" >Copy this</button>
```

.ts file:

```
copyMessage(val: string){
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.innerText = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the simplest solution for myself with pure Angular and ViewChild.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cbtest',
  template: `
    <input type="text" #inp/>
    <input type="button" (click)="copy ()" value="copy now"/>`
})

export class CbTestComponent
{
  @ViewChild ("inp") inp : any;

  copy ()
  {
    // this.inp.nativeElement.value = "blabla";  // you can set a value manually too

    this.inp.nativeElement.select ();   // select
    document.execCommand ("copy");      // copy
    this.inp.nativeElement.blur ();     // unselect
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Solution 1 of @Sangram's answer (and the comment from @Jonathan):

*(In favor of "do not use plain document in angular" and "do not add HTML elements from code if you don't have to...)*

```js
// TS

@ViewChild('textarea') textarea: ElementRef;

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

public copyToClipboard(text): void {
  console.log(`> copyToClipboard(): copied "${text}"`);
  this.textarea.nativeElement.value = text;
  this.textarea.nativeElement.focus();
  this.textarea.nativeElement.select();
  this.document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```css
/* CSS */
.textarea-for-clipboard-copy {
  left: -10000;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -10000;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea class="textarea-for-clipboard-copy" #textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer - how to copy text to clipboard.

**IN HTML**

```
<input #copy><button (click)="copyToClipboard(copy.value)">Copy To Clipboard</button>
```

**IN TS**

```
copyToClipboard(text) {
// Create a temporary textarea element to hold the text
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.value = text;

// Append the textarea to the document
document.body.appendChild(textarea);

// Select the text in the textarea
textarea.select();

// Copy the selected text to the clipboard
document.execCommand('copy');

// Remove the textarea from the document
document.body.removeChild(textarea);
```

}

**Here is the Stackblitz**

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-copytexttoclipboard?file=README.md

Answer (score -1):

```js
phoneNoAction = (mobile) => {
    $('.copy').on('click', () =>{
      navigator['clipboard'].writeText(mobile).then().catch(e =>            console.error(e));
    })
  }
```

```html
<p style="cursor: pointer;"class="card-text" (click)="phoneNoAction(item.MobileNumb)">
{{item.MobileNumb}}</p>

<button class="copy">copy mobile number</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually I'm new on this platform. Thank you for suggestion. I'll improve next time for sure.

Answer (score -2):

```
copyCurl(val: string){
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(val).then( () => {
      this.toastr.success('Text copied to clipboard');
    }).catch( () => {
      this.toastr.error('Failed to copy to clipboard');
    });
}
```