# Typescript angular 7, copy to clip board

Tags: angular, typescript, input, clipboard

I want to make a very simple input-group with an input that is disabled and a button that copies the input value to the clipboard.
When it has been copied i want a small message popping up saying it was.

Is there any good way to do this?

this method don't seem to work, and it looks like a quick fix and does not look very nice.

```
copyInputMessage(inputElement){
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

the html i got looks like this atm:

```
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" disabled value="TextToBeCopied" #inputToBeCopied/>
            <button (click)="copyInputMessage(inputToBeCopied)" value="click to copy">COPY</button>
        </div>
```

I can only find very wierd solutions, there must be a more simple way?

I've seen the solutions that already exists, no one works for me and neither does fit my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 - Copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102724/angular-5-copy-to-clipboard)

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+clipboard