# If I know the value of a string can i insert it directly onto the clipboard without doing an execCommand('copy')

Tags: javascript, typescript

Something as simple as this?

let myString = "foo";

*copyToClipboard*(myString);

Comment: the OP said he didn't want to use execCommand (wondering why....)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write

Comment: in safari, edge and internet explorer?

Comment: I was thinking execCommand('copy') required coping a manipulated selection of text, which seemed error prone compared to just giving it the text I already know.  But if that's the best way it's ok.  I'd like it to work pretty universally, yeah.

Comment: I found this post which worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121680/7636192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *two* ways to interact with the clipboard:

- `document.execCommand("copy")` < Which you said you don't want to use.
- `navigator.clipboard.write`

The support for the more modern second option is lacking though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write

There is currently no other supported way :)