# How to copy text to clipboard

Tags: angular

I am taking my first steps in Angular and I made a quote generator which is working fine; Now I want to add a button when clicked copies to clipboard the generated quote. I check some few links about copying to clipboard such as [Angular 5 - Copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102724/angular-5-copy-to-clipboard) but I do not know how to use it in my case.

This is the part in `app.component.ts` for the random part.

```
  getNewQuote($event: MouseEvent) {
    const quoteText = document.querySelector('.quote-text');
    this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.quotes.length));
    quoteText.innerHTML = this.quotes[this.randomNumber];
```

I have this in `app.component.html` for the copy button

```
    <i class="fa fa-files-o" (click)="copy()"></i>
```

I am very stuck on this I do not know how to copy the random quotes. How can I do this?

Comment: You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular provides an out-of-the-box [copy to clipboard](https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview) functionality through the cdk.

What you should do:

```
 <i class="fa fa-files-o" [cdkCopyToClipboard]="getNewQuote()"></i>
```

And don't forgot to include the module:

```
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
```

Comment: thank you. Tried that but it gives me blank page i do not know why

Comment: Oh got it  it was because of my angular version Thank you so much!