# Copy part of table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table

I have a HTML table that I want to copy to the clipboard.
However, I don't want the header row to be copied, only the rest of the table.
This is the table:

```
<table style="width:100%" #table>
    <tr>
      <th class="border"></th>
      <th class="border"></th>
      <th class="border"></th>
      <th class="border"></th>
      <th class="border"></th>
      <th class="border"></th>
    </tr>
    <ng-template ngFor let-table [ngForOf]="mCase.Tables" let-i="index">
      <ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="table.rows" let-rowIndex="index">
        <tr>
          <td>
           ....
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  </table>
```

This is the Javascript I'm using to copy it:

```
 @ViewChild('table') table: ElementRef;

 var body = document.body as HTMLElement, range, sel;
if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
  range = document.createRange();
  sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  try {
    range.selectNodeContents(this.table.nativeElement);
    sel.addRange(range);
  } catch (e) {
    range.selectNode(this.table.nativeElement);
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
} else if (body.createTextRange) {
  range = body.createTextRange();
  range.moveToElementText(this.table.nativeElement);
  range.select();
}

document.execCommand("Copy");
```

This code copies all of the table.
How do I copy the table without the header row?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328159/how-do-i-copy-to-clipboard-in-angular-2-typescript

Comment: @vbRocks The problem isn't that the table isn't being copied, but that I want to copy only part of the table, without the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in your `<table>` tags and just select only the `<tbody>`instead of selecting entire table.

**Edit**

DataTables solves this problem
Find the detailed explanation [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)

You can check youtube link for [DataTables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3kF1ZHCf8c)

Header gets selected here too. However if you wish not to you can change as per your convenience.
You should manipulate the below script

> https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js

```
exportOptions: {},
        fieldSeparator: "\t",
        fieldBoundary: "",
        header: !0,
        footer: !1,
        title: "*",
        messageTop: "*",
        messageBottom: "*"
```

You can find these from lines 286-293
As you dont want headers change it to

```
 header: !1,
```

Use this new script after changing the line.

Comment: Thanks, but it now copies it only as plain text, where before it copied it as a table.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to remove some of the selected range?

Comment: Copying entire table. Does that mean even the table borders?

Comment: No, just the contents. I want to paste it into Excel, each cell in an Excel cell. My code copies the table this way. If I copy only tbody, it pastes it as text.

Comment: Do you mind using a plugin that simplifies your task?

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Comment: Probably i didn't notice DataTables also copies headers by default. So i have edited my answer so that only body part gets selected(no headers)