# Copy a String to clipboard in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, clipboard.js

I have a method in `Angular2` that generates a sharable link which is something like a `requestPath`. On button click, I need to copy this `requestPath` to clipboard. How to achieve that?

I came across multiple [copy-to-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36330518/1471314) solutions here but nothing meets my need. I do not have a `textArea` or any `input` element to copy from. Just a simple string variable needed to be copied `onClick`

The html I have is:

```
<td class="submitBtnCell">
    <button class="btn" (click)="createSharableLink()">Share</button>
</td>
```

and method:

```
createSharableLink(){
    let requestPath = this.prepareRequestPathForVideos("shared");
    alert(requestPath); // need to copy this request path to clipboard       
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that link and it is not the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet I've used in one of my previous projects which allows you to copy things to your clipboard.

Also mentioned by [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4269187/carsten) below.

```
// Copy Element Into Clipboard [ Can use "$(val).text()" as Argument ]
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(element).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

It appends a hidden `<input>` to the body of the page, adds your element to it, selects the text and uses `execCommand` to copy the selected text.

Using your code, here's an example:

```
<td class="submitBtnCell">
    <button class="btn" (click)="createSharableLink()">Share</button>
</td>

createSharableLink(){
    let requestPath = this.prepareRequestPathForVideos("shared");
    //alert(requestPath); // need to copy this request path to clipboard   
    copyToClipboard(requestPath);  
}
```

**Reference**: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables

**StackOverflow Link:** [angular2 style guide - property with dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign)

> Because Angular applications are mostly written in TypeScript, you
>   will typically know when a variable is an observable. Although the
>   Angular framework does not enforce a naming convention for
>   observables, you will often see observables named with a trailing “$”
>   sign.
>
> This can be useful when scanning through code and looking for
>   observable values. Also, if you want a property to store the most
>   recent value from an observable, it can be convenient to simply use
>   the same name with or without the “$”.

Comment: Am new to Angular. Don't know how to use `$` in here.

Comment: Read the references roger, the code will work, `$` is just a naming convention.

Comment: Also `$` is used a lot in Angular. It is scope variable, but it works in a different context too.

Comment: Thanks Alex but am talking about this statement `$("<input>")` where am getting the error.

Comment: I guess this is more of a Jquery context.

Comment: Solved. I had to use `import * as $ from 'jquery';` statement to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you cannot directly access the clipboard. You can create a hidden input element, set the text in there and trigger the copy functionality from it.